# German postpositions

Tags: preposition

The German adpositions are predominantly prepositions, with some cases such as [entlang](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entlang) that can be used both as a preposition and a postposition.

are there any adposition in German that are used only as postpositions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This source](http://www.ghochlaender.de/LingDidaktik/praepositionen.htm) is pretty comprehensive... 
according to it, the post-onlys are

**"halber"** and **"zuliebe"**

... I would add "zufolge" to that list but Wikipedia disagrees. Still sounds weird to me when before a noun.

Comment: Dem kann ich (als Muttersprachler) nur zustimmen. Mir fällt spontan kein Nomen ein, vor dem "zufolge" verwendet werden kann, ohne dass ein merkwürdig klingender Satz entsteht.

Comment: "Zufolge" follows Dativ but precedes Genitiv, as in "dem Bericht zufolge" or "zufolge des Berichts".

Comment: Jop, [so isses](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zufolge)